# seaborn ignores custom color palette when number of patches exceeds number of colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I set up a palette containing just black and gray as follows.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_palette(['#000000', '#ABABAB'])
```

This works fine if I just have two or less patches in my plot.

```
sns.barplot([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

[image]

However, when I have more bars than colors, `seaborn` switches back to the default palette.

```
sns.barplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

[image]

Can I make `seaborn` cycle through my custom color palette? In the case above, the first bar should be black, the second grey and the third one black again.

My current workaround is

```
sns.set_palette(['#000000', '#ABABAB']*1000)
```

but I doubt this is the standard way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple as per the official docs. Just set `n_colors` to be **more than** the number of colors in the palette. Below is the relevant information (highlighted **in bold**). Here you can just set `n_colors` to a large number. Anything more than 2 will work in your case.

> n_colors : int, optional
>       Number of colors in the palette. If `None`, the default will depend
>       on how `palette` is specified. Named palettes default to 6 colors,
>       but grabbing the current palette or passing in a list of colors will
>       not change the number of colors unless this is specified. **Asking for
>       more colors than exist in the palette will cause it to cycle.**

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_palette(['#000000', '#ABABAB'], n_colors=100)

sns.barplot([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

**EDIT** It seems that one has to have to `n_colors` also more than the number of patches (bars in this case). So if there are two colors in the palette and 4 patches, then `n_colors` should be also more than both (>4 in this case).

[image]

Comment: Sorry to bother you. "Asking for more colors than exist in the palette will cause it to cycle." does not seem to work correctly for me. `sns.set_palette(['#000000', '#ABABAB'], n_colors=3)` followed by `sns.barplot([1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,5])` gives the standard color palette. It works with `n_colors=4`. Seems like you need to set `n_colors` to how many patches you expect, but this is not how I understand the documentation.

Comment: @actual_panda: No, the point here is that `n_colors` should be **more** than the number of colors in the palette. Do you see my point? So for `sns.barplot([1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,5])`, you should use `n_colors` more than 4. So the safest option here is to set `n_colors` to a really large number.

Comment: Are we using the same terms? There are two colors in the palette (3 > 2). There are four patches in the plot (3 < 4).

Comment: Ok, I see the point here. I think the number has to be larger than also the number of patches. So the safest option here is to put n_colors some large number. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried `sns.set_palette(colors, n_colors=np.iinfo(np.int64).max)` but this operation never finishes. It seems like internally something similar to my workaround is used. Looks like there's no cleaner solution than something like `sns.set_palette(colors, n_colors=10000)`.

Comment: @actual_panda: If you have really a large dataset, then I think yeah, that seems reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187014/discussion-between-bazingaa-and-actual-panda).